# Can't find the marble node texture (Eevee or Cycles)?

Tags: texturing

Where can I find  the marble node texture in either Eevee or Cycles rendering ,because it's very hard for me to see it. And also can someone let me know if it has been removed or combined with another texture. Thank You

Comment: The Marble texture may have existed in the Shader Editor but it looks like it's not the case anymore, it's part of the other texture system of Blender though, the one that you'll find in the Texture panel, which is a completely different system (that you can use for modifiers for example)

Comment: Hi :). The marble node is a part of the old [Texture Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/texture_node/types/textures/marble.html). It has never been in the shader editor.

Comment: @Jachym Michal So where were they available? The image shows a node that looks like a Shader Editor node

Comment: @moonboots Blender manual says it's available in Texture Nodes, but i've never used those :)). [They look similar to other node editors](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/_images/editors_texture-node_introduction_types-combined.png)

Comment: Oh ok I've never paid attention to this editor and I'm not sure what exactly it is for